# Displaying Concatenated Values from Common Attribute in a Row

Tags: looker-studio, looker

I'm new to Google Looker and I'm looking for a way to concatenate 2 values and display them in a third row in my report that I'm building using only the formula editor when creating a new field.

Here is a representation of my table in Looker

I have a row with IDs and I want to create a field and add a formula where it can see which IDs have the same date/time and concat them in a third row. I have added a table as an example

| ID | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Jan 11, 2024, 9:35 pm |
| 145 | Jan 11, 2024, 9:35 pm |
| 166 | Jan 13, 2024, 8:05 pm |
| 154 | Jan 11, 2024, 2:53 pm |